# nested for-loop in R language

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I have this code to calculate duplicate in a data frame using cosine similarity through firstly: first loop (nrow) times to take in each time one tweet then compares the cosine similarity results to this tweet with other tweets using second loop.

Here is my code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
  dup=0
  one_Tweets = tweets$Tweet[i]
  cos_similarity = data.frame("v1"=NULL) # NULL So that don't write previous value
  cos_similarity=data.frame(sim <- round( sim.strings(AllTweets,one_Tweets), digits = 3) )
  names(cos_similarity) = c( "v1")

  for (b in i+1:nrow(temp)) {
    Tweet_cos=cos_similarity$v1[b]
    if ( Tweet_cos >= 0.900) {
      count = count+1
      tweets$flag[b]= 1
    }else { #if ( Tweet_cos <0.900) {
      tweets$flag[b]= 2
    }
    Tweet_cos=0
  }
  dup=tweets$duplicate[i]= tweets$duplicate[i]+count 
  count = 0
}
```

I have a problem in first loop, entered one time although that number of tweets in data frame 10000 tweets.

and i get the error:

```
Error in if (Tweet_cos >= 0.9) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: try `summary(temp)` to see whether you  have `NA` values in the Tweet_cos

Comment: in Environment  Tweet_cos value = NA_real_, after use summary (temp) i see values

Comment: see result:     `summary(Tweet_cos)
       Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
         NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA       1`

Comment: pay attention to the fact that `i+1:nrow(temp)`is not the same as `(i+1):nrow(temp)`

Comment: I added loop outside  `k=i+1` then I wrote loop condition `for (b in k: nrow (temp))` this solve loop problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont still have rep to put it in comment but I think you are getting this problem because of NA/NULL in Tweet_cos vector. to debug remove this part from code:

```
    for (b in i+1:nrow(temp)) {
    Tweet_cos=cos_similarity$v1[b]
    if ( Tweet_cos >= 0.900) {
      count = count+1
      tweets$flag[b]= 1
    }else { #if ( Tweet_cos <0.900) {
      tweets$flag[b]= 2
    }
    Tweet_cos=0
  }
  dup=tweets$duplicate[i]= tweets$duplicate[i]+count 
  count = 0
```

replace whole of this with `print(cos_similarity$v1)`. You should ideally see some NA/NULL which by def could not be compared with 0.9 and hence the error.

If there are too many iterations/loop then try to print values of `i` and `b` where you are getting error and print `cos_similarity$v1` only for that.

Please consider sharing small sample data so that others can replicate your problem

Comment: i remove this part and print cos_similarity$V1 .. Result: `[2205] 0.489 0.615 0.699 0.649 0.616 0.757 0.603 0.666 0.669 0.616 0.716 0.658 0.649 0.682 0.740 0.578 0.696 0.661 0.719
[2224] 0.737 0.734 0.631 0.724 0.721 0.690 0.544 0.645 0.617 0.618 0.586 0.600 0.539 0.594 0.716 0.637 0.674 0.699 0.582`